# Github Pages as Static Image Hosting

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, random

I am trying to use GitHub pages to host static images for a website I am working on. The website randomizes div locations across the page, and it's supposed to use the photos from the repository. Here is the [repository](https://github.com/elimcgehee/staticimages) that is hosting the images.

The issue is that the images are not loading from the Github pages. Am I not referencing the photos correctly in the Javascript? Here is a [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imGNP.jpg) that shows what the page looks like when I run it. As you can see, none of the images load into the webpage. Not sure if I am referencing the photo incorrectly in the JS, or if I need to add any HTML code to reference the photos. Either way, I would really appreciate any help. :)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js" integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->

</head>
<body>
    <h1><b>Issy B. Designs</b></h1><br>
    <div class="random"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const imgPoss = [];

let maxX, maxY;

function placeImg() {
    const NUM_OF_IMAGES = 90; // set this to however images you have in the directory.
    const randImg = Math.random() * NUM_OF_IMAGES;
    const imgSrc = 'https://elimcgehee.github.io/staticimages/gallery/' + randImg.toString() + '.png';

    const {random: r} = Math;  
    const x = r() * maxX;
    const y = r() * maxY;
    
    if(!isOverlap(x,y)) {
        var link = `<img class="random" style="left: ${x}px; top: ${y}px;" src="${imgSrc}" />`;
        var bodyHtml = document.body.innerHTML;
        document.body.innerHTML = bodyHtml + link;
        
        imgPoss.push({x, y}); // record all img positions
    }
}

function isOverlap(x, y) { // return true if overlapping
    const img = {x: 128, y:160};
    
    for(const imgPos of imgPoss) {
        if( x>imgPos.x-img.x && x<imgPos.x+img.x &&
            y>imgPos.y-img.y && y<imgPos.y+img.y ) return true;
    }
    return false;
}

onload = function() {
    maxX = innerWidth - 128;
    maxY = innerHeight - 160;
    setInterval(placeImg, 10);
}

onresize = function() {
    maxX = innerWidth - 128;
    maxY = innerHeight - 160;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript Math.random() returns float between 0 and 1. By multiplying it by 90 you get a float, but all your photos are intigers. And since your pictures start from 10.png it should look like this

```
const NUM_OF_IMAGES = 90; // set this to however images you have in the directory.
const START_OF_IMAGES = 10;
    const randImg = Math.round(Math.random() * NUM_OF_IMAGES + START_OF_IMAGES);
    const imgSrc = 'https://elimcgehee.github.io/staticimages/gallery/' + randImg.toString() + '.png';
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you so much!